# confusion with promise then function

Tags: javascript, promise

```
var p3 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
  resolve( "B" );
});

var p1 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
  resolve( p3 );
});
```

with above sequence of promise creation can someone tell me how both of the following statements print same value,

### Statement 1:

```
p1
    .then( ( p3promiseObj ) => p3promiseObj )
    .then( p3val => console.log( p3val ) )
```

*Output*:

```
B
Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
```

### Statement 2:

```
p1.then((val)=>console.log(val))
```

*Output*:

```
B
Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
```

statement 1 makes sense to me as `p1` is resolved to `p3promiseObj` ,then from `p3promiseObj` we can get resolved value `"B"`.

statement 2 gets `p3` promise object, not resolved value... so how does it print `"B"` instead of Promise object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `p1` is **already** resolved to `p3`, thanks to this line in the promise executor:

```
var p1 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
  resolve( p3 ); // <==========
});
```

Since `p3` is a promise, calling `resolve(p3)` resolves the promise (`p1`) to the promise in `p3`.

---

Note that your "Statement 1" code is incorrect, in two ways:

1. The JavaScript promise implementation will never pass a promise or thenable into `then`. Instead, it will only call `then` when the promise is *fulfilled" (passing in the fulfillment value). The fulfillment value in a [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant implementation (which JavaScript's is) can never be a promise or a thenable, because the promise you call `then` on would have resolved to it instead of being fulfilled by it.
2. There's never any point to `.then(x => x)`.

Comment: got it thanks for explanation. i logged value "p3promiseObj " in statement 1 in first then call and it's already value "B".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant part of the Specs:

[25.4.3.1 Promise ( executor )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor):

> The `resolve` function that is passed to an executor function accepts a single argument. The executor code may eventually call the `resolve` function to indicate that it wishes to resolve the associated Promise object. The argument passed to the `resolve` function represents the eventual value of the deferred action and **can be either the actual fulfillment value or another Promise object which will provide the value if it is fulfilled.**

So you can either pass fulfillment directly or a Promise. If it is a Promise, then the fullfilment value of that Promise is used as soon as the Promise is fullfilled:

```js
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("B"), 1000);
});

var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(p3);
});

p1
  .then(val => console.log(val))
```

That does also work if `p3` is rejected:

```js
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("B")), 1000);
});

var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(p3);
});

p1
  .then(p3val => console.log('resolved to:' + p3val))
  .catch(err => console.error('rejected:', err))
```

If the then able object is implemented according to the Promise/A+ specs then `.then( ( p3promiseObj ) => p3promiseObj )` will always be pointless, as the first argument of the then fulfillment callback is always the resolved value.

Answer (score -1):

That's because in the statement `p1.then( ( p3promiseObj ) => p3promiseObj )`, `p3promiseObj` returns a value `B`. And this value is not a promise, so the next `.then` function would return `undefined.`

```js
var p3 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
  resolve( "B" );
});
var p1 = new Promise( function(resolve,reject){
  resolve( p3 );
});

p1.then(p3val=>console.log(p3val));
```

Comment: _"And this value is not a promise, so the next `.then` function would return undefined."_ - With this explanation there would not be a _"next `.then` function"_. `.then()` will always return a Promise. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then): _"If a handler function: **returns a value, the promise returned by `then`** gets resolved with the returned value as its value."_

Comment: @Tan , .then() always return promise.the promise returned gets resolved to value provided in handler , if no value provided , the returned promise will be resolved to undefined.